# Converting chararray to int in pig?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, analytics

in Pig Analytics I have a database that has date in **'dd-MMM-YYYY' like 11-Dec-1985**.Thats the birthdate.How do i get the age from it?And do some other Operations.Basically after exctracting **how do i convert chararray to int type** 
or any other possible way you suggest i can do.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you use pig's ToDate builtin UDF ?
http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.17.0/func.html#to-date